# Upsample non-time data to integer meters

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation

I use Python 3 and want to upsample one data series like this:

- distance (meters)  ,   elevation(meters)
- 00.00 , 439.2
- 20.36  ,      462.7
- 61.70   ,       480.4
- ...      ,         ...
- Name: elevation(meters), dtype: float64

To be like this (with linear interpolation):

- distance (meters)   ,  elevation(meters)
- 00.00     ,      439.2
- 01.00    ,             440.4
- 02.00    ,             441.6
- 03.00     ,            442.7
- 04.00     ,            443.9
- 05.00      ,           445.1
- ...        ,           ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the scientific python library's [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and [numpy](https://numpy.org/) as an approach.

First you have to install both:

```
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

Now you can use / import them in your python instance:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

After this you should init a pandas [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with your data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'meters':[0.0], 'elevation': [439.2]})
```

Now i would suggest to reindex the data by using numpys arange function:

```
df2 = df.reindex(np.arange(0.0, 62, 0.01))
```

Set the values for 20.36 and 61.70:

(Maybe there is a smarter solution, but lets use this as a workaround.)

```
df2.set_value(20.36, 'meters', 20.36)
df2.set_value(20.36, 'elevation', 462.7)

df2.set_value(61.70, 'meters', 61.70)
df2.set_value(61.70, 'elevation', 480.4)
```

Now we can make use of [pandas linear interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df3 = df2.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
```

And finally get our desired data:

```
>>> df3[0:100:100]
      meters   elevation
0.0      0.0  439.200000
1.0      1.0  440.354224
2.0      2.0  441.508448
3.0      3.0  442.662672
4.0      4.0  443.816896
...      ...         ...
58.0    58.0  478.815820
59.0    59.0  479.243977
60.0    60.0  479.672134
61.0    61.0  480.100290
```

Comment: Thanks zerocewl, it worked out well!! I really appreciate this! But perhaps there are some easier way to solve it. I would appreciate if you or someone else on Stack Overflow have time and energy to think about how to make this more easy, because I am going to do this procedure for a lot of data-sets with different elevations.

Comment: ... and the data-series are 1000 rows long! I just showed the first three rows.